# "Invalid sender" message when sending rawTransaction to Ropsten via infura

Tags: react-native, web3js

[image: Error]
I'm trying to send rawTransactions to Ropsten network via infura. 
These are the libraries that I use in my React Native project.

I have been struggling this for few weeks. Please advise.
Someone suggested I should implement the r,v,s into the rawTransaction message. I'm not sure that will solve the issue and how can I get r,v,s?

```
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress,'pending', (error, nounce) => {
      console.log('This is the nouce'+ web3.toHex(nounce))
      var data = _myContract.transfer.getData(toAddress, 10000);
      var gasPrice = 1;
      var gasLimit =3000000;
      const chain_id =3;
      const gas = 21000;
      var rawTransaction = {
        "from": fromAddress,
        "nonce": web3.toHex(nounce),
        "gasPrice": web3.toHex(gasPrice),
        "gasLimit": web3.toHex(gasLimit),
        "to": toAddress,
        "value":'0x00',
        "data": data,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gas":gas
      };

        var privKey = new Buffer('key', 'hex');
        var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);

        tx.sign(privKey);
        var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
       console.log('RawTransaction :' + '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
       web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
        if (!err)
            console.log(hash);
        else
            console.log(err);
      });
    })
```